# Symplectic time-integrator for Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, differential-equations, stochastic-processes

Is there a way to use a symplectic time-integrator for the numerical solution [Fokker-Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation) of the form: 
$$\partial_{t}p = -\nabla \cdot (\underline{v}p - D\nabla p)~?$$ where $p = p(\underline{x}, t)$ is the probability density, $\underline{v}$ is the constant velocity field and $D$ is the scalar diffusion constant. Currently, I am solving the equation using [A practical difference scheme for Fokker-Planck equations](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002199917090001X)  to perform the spacial discretisation, but was wondering if there were any symplectic integrators.

Comment: Hi, my apologies. $p = p(\underline{x}, t)$ is the probability density, $\underline{v}$ is the constant velocity field and $D$ is the scalar diffusion constant. Currently, I am solving the equation using https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/002199917090001X?token=4FBD6C419ACBBCEDEBA3211BCFC3833D88E1DFE225537BC05D57CE1441CE4341B78C5CDC119C42048023EC7BF7295908 to perform the spacial discretisation, but was wondering if there were any symplectic integrators

Comment: Thank you. Actually the post would get more attention if this information were added to the post directly. Thx